# 200 Concurrent Download Using Robocopy From a Single AWS Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008, robocopy

Robocopy is exactly what I need for my project. The only thing is that I need to have one server with 500GB of data and have 200 machines download that data from this server concurrently. Is this doable by robocopy.

All the machines are Windows 2008 and they are all in the aws. I have the freedom to pick the beefiest machine in aws but wondering if a setup like that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your data in [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) as your data store. You will get much better performance this way, and it will save you the cost of this central server.

You can also use [BitTorrent protocol against the S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html) files, utilising your distribution even better. Or you can simply download the files directly to each machine from S3.

Putting the files on S3 is also safer as it has better redundancy than a single server storage.

Comment: S3 is not fast when many machines try to download the same life. On the other hand, the s3 bit torrent is limited to 5g files which is show stopper for me.